# Неверно переписывается изображение OpenCV python

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, opencv

Разбираюсь с обработкой изображений на python с OpenCV. Возникла следующая проблема: Если я просто перекладываю массив изображения в новый массив, то изображение сильно высветляется. Как будто я пишу туда только белые пиксели.
Вот код:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread("test1.png")
print(img.shape)
line, row = img.shape[:2]
new_img = np.zeros([line, row, 3])
i = 0
while i < line:
    j = 0
    while j < row:
        new_img[i, j, 0] = img[i, j, 0]
        new_img[i, j, 1] = img[i, j, 1]
        new_img[i, j, 2] = img[i, j, 2]
        j += 1
    i += 1

cv.imshow("Image", new_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

в качестве входного изображения я подаю просто серый прямоугольник размера 19х21. Но при выводе new_img получаю белый прямоугольник.

Судя по отладчику, массив переписывается верно.
(заранее прошу прощение если что-то назвал не своими именами, в мире python недавно)

Comment: В исходном нет альфа-канала? Гамма-коррекции?

Comment: неа, там проблема с приведением типов

Comment: Я не вижу, чтобы Вы как-то обеспечили одинаковый формат изображений

Comment: Я добавил ответ на вопрос. Вы правы я не сделал приведение типов и из-за этого получалась ерунда.

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо, что откликнулись :)

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался. При создании массива `np.zeros([line, row, 3])` ячейка массива создается с типом `numpy.float64`. Но пиксели изображения имеют формат 8 битного беззнакового целого числа, то есть `numpy.uint8` .
Необходимо сделать приведение типа:
`new_img = new_img.astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Ну вообще-то как и почти в любых других функциях `Numpy`, создающих массивы, в `np.zeros` можно сразу указать нужный тип данных через параметр `dtype=np.uint8`

Comment: @CrazyElf Вы правы, я этого не знал и поэтому совершил такую очевидную ошибку.